# Mongo Script to match element using Like in array element

Tags: mongodb

I am trying on a mongo script to find all records that match a particular criteria.

I have collection:

```
collection1:
{
_id:ObjectId("60a663c933649ayu9i")
name:"ABCTech"
}
{
_id:ObjectId("60a998933649ayu9i")
name:"CDTech"
}

collection2
{
_id:ObjectId("70a663c933649ayu9i")
col1_id:ObjectId("60a663c933649ayu9i")
email:['abc@gmail.com','pq@gmail.com']
date:2021-05-28T07:03:51.331+00:00
}
```

input would be name from collection1(ABCTech) and just name in email(abc)

output would be fields that match above condition:

```
result
{
email:['abc@gmail.com','pq@gmail.com']
date:2021-05-28T07:03:51.331+00:00
}
```

I have tried below script:

```
let col1= db.collection1.findOne({name:"ABCTech"});
let id=col1._id;


let col2=db.collection2.findOne(
{col1_id:id;email:{ $regex: ".*abc.*"}}
)

print("result = ", tojson(id));
print("Result 2 =",tojson(col2));
```

However,I am not getting desired result.
Could someone help in tweaking this one.

Comment: the field name `arr` is incorrect in the second collection query, it should be `email` as per your collection data.

Comment: sorry,i was actually changing the variable names from original code to have it posted here,but  even with it being replaced by email doest work

Comment: what is the problem? are you getting data in first query? there is one more issue in second query `col1_id:id;` semicolon. in object is incorrect it should be comma `,`.

Comment: Okay,yes I replaced it with comma and I am now getting output,however I get all fields from collections 2,i only need email and date.

Comment: use prokection in second parameter `findObe({},  { email: 1, date: 1 })`